# Is it possible to use a for loop in postgresql (Function)

Tags: postgresql, function, for-loop, plpgsql

Is it possible to use a for loop in postgresql (Function)

Comment: Yes. Read documentaion for more details

Comment: No. Don't read the documentation

Comment: Possibly.  Hope the documentation finds you

Answer (score 0):

In a word - yes. The syntax is quite simple and straightforward:

```
FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
    -- Do something with i
END LOOP;
```

You can also go backwards (by using the `REVERSE` keyword before specifying the range) and control the size of the step by using a `BY` clause.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS) for the complete details.